# How to push attr value in array jquery/javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to push the value of attr in array but whenever I push it shows me count number of how many times I clicked on the button not pushing value in the array. help, please!

*//Below code HTML*

```
<div class="container">
      <button class="btn green" id="green"></button>
      <button class="btn red" id="red"></button><br />
      <button class="btn yellow" id="yellow"></button>
      <button class="btn blue" id="blue"></button>
    </div>
```

*//Below code is jQuery*

```
 $(".btn").click(function () {
        var userClickedPattern = [];
        var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(userChosenColor);
        console.log(userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor));
    
    });
```

*//Below the result I am getting*
[Result in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRrQW.png)

Comment: [MDN push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) *adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.*

Comment: Add `console.log(userClickedPattern)` after the .push.  Most vanilla js functions can't be used for chaining.

Comment: `.push()` modifies your array, so you shouldn't be logging the return value of `.push()` (which is the new length after adding your value), but instead the array itself. You're also creating your array each time you click `var userClickedPattern = [];`, which should be outside of the click event handler if you want it to accumulate per click (otherwise you reset it by overwriting it each click)

Comment: First do push, and than console.log the Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are logging the wrong code if you want to see the new array you should do something like this:

```
 userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor)
    console.log(userClickedPattern);
```